# Output text in Java shifted half a space

Tags: java, text, printf, output

I am trying to horizontally display matrices of different sizes.
I'm using a the BlueJ terminal window for my output.
Printing the matrices works if the matrix on the left has more rows than the ones that follow, however when it has less rows the following matrices are out of alignment. Pictures below.

[image: current output]

An obvious solution might be to get rid of one space that comes before the second matrix (after the first matrix has ended), but this yields the following result:

[image: alternate output]

Code used to produce spacing before rows of the second matrix:

```
System.out.printf("%"+Integer.toString((width*numElements) + (numElements+4)) + "s", " ");
```

Where `width` is equal to the length of the largest value in the matrix and `numElements` is equal to the number of elements in each row of the matrix.

How do align these matrices correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you show your code ? Also did you try padding + using tabs to align matrix to grids ?

Comment: Yes. Now that I am looking into it more, the alignment issue might be a result of using a monospaced font which is known to cause alignment errors in java.

Answer (score 2):

Some monospaced fonts will incorrectly display spaces in certain situations in java. At least for the program I am using (BlueJ) text that should be vertically aligned is off by a little bit. It turns out that this "little bit" is exactly 5/6 of a regular space character. So to counteract the misalignment produced by the program just add a 5/6 space character before the line that is misaligned. To achieve a 5/6 space character in java use the following code:

```
String five_sixth_space = String.valueOf((char)8194)+String.valueOf((char)8198)+String.valueOf((char)8198);
```

Comment: This seems like a hacky, won't-work-cross-platform kinda fix though.  Seems like a better fix would be to fix the underlying issue, like fix what causes the 5/6 display

Comment: Ur right, but I just wanted my homework for my CS class to look nice. So for that it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `System.out.println();` before the print statements, it should work in BlueJ.